# Let $R = \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z = \{\bar 0,...\bar5\}$. In the polynomial ring $R[x]$ compute the product of the polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-function

Let $R = \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z = \{\bar 0,...\bar5\}$. In the polynomial ring $R[x]$ compute the product of the polynomials
$f = \bar2x^2+\bar3x +\bar1\,,\, g = \bar3x^3 +\bar4x^2 +\bar2$

My attempt:

$$\begin{align}f\cdot g &=(\bar2x^2+\bar3x +\bar1)(\bar3x^3 +\bar4x^2 +\bar2)\\
&=(\bar6x^5+\bar9x^4+\bar8x^4)+(\bar3x^3+\bar{12}x^3+\bar4x^2)+(\bar4x^2+\bar6x+\bar2)
\\&=\bar6x^5+\bar{17}x^4+\bar{15}x^3+\bar8x^2+\bar6x+\bar2\\
&=\bar0x^5+\bar5x^4+\bar3x^3+\bar2x^2+\bar0x+\bar2\\
&=\bar5x^4+\bar3x^3+\bar2x^2+\bar2
\end{align}$$

Is this correct? I'm pretty sure it is correct, but it's nice to double check.

Thanks!

Comment: It's correct for me, albeit  somewhat too long.

Comment: Thanks for checking! When I learn new things it's nice to make sure I'm doing it right. :)

Comment: You might simplify, writing directly, say, $3^2=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your result is correct.

One way to check is to look at the product modulo $2$ and $3$.

I'll avoid the bars for some typing speed.

Modulo $2$, you have $f=x+1$ and $g=x^3$ so $fg=x^4+x^3$.

Modulo $3$, you have that $f=2x^2+1$ and $g=x^2+2$ so $fg=2x^4+2x^2+2$.

These agree with your result.